# A peculiar fact about studying the rate of change of physical quantities

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

This question arose from me trying to understand the link between variations of physical quantities with respect to different, but related, variables. However, the question is more about understanding the meaning of the math behind it.

Say we have a function $$R(\rho)=k\rho$$ (physically $R$ could be the electrical resistance of a material, $\rho$ its electrical resistivity, and $k$ a proportionality constant.) Then, we have $\frac{dR}{d\rho} = k$; the rate-of-change of $R$ (wrt $\rho$) is constant and independent of $\rho$.

Now, say I write $R$ as a function of the variable $\sigma=\frac{1}{\rho}$ (physically this would be the electrical conductivity of the material), i.e.,
$$R(\sigma) = \frac{k}{\sigma}$$
Then we have $\frac{dR}{d\sigma} = \frac{-k}{\sigma^2}$; the rate-of-change of $R$ (wrt $\sigma$) is not only not constant but also dependents (nonlinearly) on $\sigma$.

**This Boggles my mind**!
Even though the math is quite simple, clear, understandable, and all you want... I fail to see how can this shift in perspective in what variable we study the function under (this seemingly *naive* change of variable; from resistivity to conductivity, which from a physics point-of-view say the same thing about what's happening in the material...), leads to this much difference between the description of variation of the function itself.

Any insights on that are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t see a contradiction. All $$\frac{dR}{d\sigma} =-\frac{k}{\sigma^2} $$ is saying is that as $\frac{1}{\rho} $ changes by a small amount, the amount which $R$ changes by is dependent on the value of $\rho$.

Saying $$\frac{dR}{d\rho} = k$$ is entirely different, as in this case we look at small changes to $\rho$ instead, and this tells us that $R$ will change by the same amount, no matter the value of $\rho$.

Comment: Thanks for re-framing it in a way that's easier to understand.

Comment: @Likely No problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not mind boggling.

The resistance $R$ is linearly dependent on the resistivity $\rho$, whilst it is inversely proportional to the conductivity.

$\rho$ and $\sigma$ are two very different physical quantities with a different physical meaning. It's rather obvious that the rate of change of $R$ with respect to $\rho$ behaves in a very different way than the rate of change of $R$ wrt $\sigma$.

It's like to have

$$f(x) = kx$$ and

$$f(x) = \dfrac{k}{x}$$

The first function is a straight line; the second one is an equilateral hyperbola. The rate of change of $f(x)$ wrt x clearly differs.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that it's not mind boggling, at least not to most people. Still, this small thing boggles my little mind :-)

Comment: @Likely Perhaps I have been too rigid, due to "experience". But I understand what you say, and I do agree that little things do boggle! :)